# excel.exe doesn't quit (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
        Dim oXL As Object
        Dim oWB As Object
        Dim oSheet As Object
        ' Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oXL.Visible = True
        ' Get a new workbook.
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
        oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet
        .........
        oXL.Quit()
        oWB = Nothing
        oXL = Nothing
        oSheet = Nothing
```

I can see the application opened in task manager ... Why ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what @Afnan Makhdoom said, but not only what he said you also need to call...

```
 GC.Collect()
```

This cleans up the objects being used and will remove it from task manager. Just releasing the objects won't remove it from task manager, you need to force the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this so it will remove the task manager process after you open the excel file:

```
 Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process

        For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
            proc.Kill()
 Next
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is release the objects first, it will surely exit the Excel.exe

```
oSheet.Close(False)
oXL.Quit()
releaseObject(oXL)
releaseObject(oWB)
releaseObject(oSheet)
oWB = Nothing
oXL = Nothing
oSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: you can use GC.Collect but @MrCoDeXeR before saying "That won't work" be sure that you have the full understanding of someone's answer, it is not a good thing to criticize others, you posted your answer, good for you, don't budge in in other's answers, RESPECT OTHERS too!

Comment: and for your information, it works -.-

Comment: No it doesn't it won't be released from task manager without GC.Collect... here's a nice example of this you may find interesting fitting his exact issue...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit

Comment: Also I mentioned you in the post, but I felt the need to criticize it. No feelings here, just constructive criticism.

Comment: Wait, here's another one that I answered with the same issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595141/visual-basics-not-closing-excel/24596883#24596883

Comment: I'm sure I fully understand too, no need to remind me.

Comment: Dude stick to your answer. Don't brother to comment here again. PS I checked my code and it is working perfectly fine