# Visual Basics not closing excel when range is used

Tags: vb.net, excel, com

In a previous post ([Excel application not quitting after calling quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit)) there's a "tried and tested" method of doing this.

I have a problem with this, in that, as it is written, it doesn't work for me.

VB 2010, Excel 2010

My Excel instance is *not* clearing out of the task manager when I release the Object. However, if I comment out *all* references to range, it works.

Why is RANGE messing it up, and how do I solve it?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
    Dim xlApp As New excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As excel.Range
    'Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlWorkSheet = DirectCast(xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1"), excel.Worksheet)

    xlApp.Visible = True



    Dim alphabet() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToUpper.ToCharArray

    xlRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2:C23")

    xlRange.Select()
    xlWorkSheet.Paste()

    xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
    xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone

    With xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1 'black
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    End With
    With xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1 'black
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    End With
    With xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1 'black
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    End With
    With xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1 'black
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    End With
    With xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1 'black
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin
    End With
    With xlRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1 'black
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin
    End With


    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="e:\Word1.xls", FileFormat:=56)
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    'xlRange = Nothing

    xlApp.Quit()

    ReleaseObject(xlRange)
    ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    ReleaseObject(xlApp)
    End Sub


    Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        Dim intRel As Integer = 0
        Do
        intRel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        Loop While intRel > 0
        Debug.Print("Final Released obj # " & intRel)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print("Error releasing object" & ex.ToString)
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints on the releaseobject to see if any exceptions have been thrown?

Comment: Also after the releasecomobject line, can you put GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers...

Comment: Yes, I've put break points in. NO exceptions. All releases work fine ("Final Released obj # 0") Excel does not vanish until I quit the program. Putting WaitForPendingFinalizers after gc.collect makes no difference.

Comment: When i get booted up at work, ill see what i can do to replicate this issue...

Comment: Tried some further testing. If I comment out all the .Borders() section, it works. Adding these back in one at a time shows that up to 3 .Borders() will still let the final release work. However, if I have a fourth .Borders() Excel does not disappear from the Task Manager until the app quits... Why? ...and how do I "release" the .Borders()?

Comment: Have you tried releasing the xlRange.Borders before...in ReleaseObject ?

Comment: I know any Excel object you use must be released. So you can start wkth what ive said above. Then try linestyles and so on....

Comment: Tried that this morning. :-) Throws an error when releasing the Borders - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8

Comment: Im going to work on replicating this issue today...

Comment: Mr CoDeXeR - any progress?