# Excel workbook, folder and picture files not closing/ending completely

Tags: vb.net, excel

This project I am working on below is a reference card that pulls text from an excel file and pictures from the same searched folder. The process is then "looped" by calling the Subs one after another until the app is exited. The reference card is supposed to update every 10 minute by researching for the files and repeating the process. The issue is that I wanted the code to open the file, pull, and then close the file completely then wait and repeat. This way the file could be edited before the next update. Instead it says it is still in use, meaning read only. Even when I close the app and visual studios it still says still in use. Using `Marshal.ObjectRelease` isn't working. The code starts the Excel Process, goes through out the code and release does not work. After it loops through the 2nd time and creates a new process (Now 2 Excel Processes) The release works but only for the new process not the original and this continues for each loop through.

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
  Dim appXL As Excel.Application
  Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
  Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim FldPath As String
  Dim PartID As String
  Dim RefCard As String
  Dim timeUpDate As Double


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Dispaly Brembo Logo
    picLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

End Sub

Private Sub Wait()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(600000)
    ReferenceCardDataPull()
End Sub
Private Async Sub ReferenceCardDataPull()

    'Read File Source with part number ******************
    PartID = ("19.N111.10")

    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = False

    'Open Reference Card*************************************************************************************
    FldPath = ("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Kaizens\Kaizen 44 - Missing Parts\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number" & "\" & PartID)
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(FldPath) Then
        wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Open(FldPath & "\" & PartID & ".xlsm")
        shXL = wbXl.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Copys Reference Card Data by Cell To App labels
        lblCODE.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 5).Value
        lblREV.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 5).Value
        lblDate.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 5).Value
        lblCustomer.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 1).Value
        lblPart.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 1).Value
        lblSpindleType.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 1).Value
        lblPaintType.Text = shXL.Cells(12, 1).Value
        lblDunnageType.Text = shXL.Cells(15, 1).Value
        lblPartsLayer.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 3).Value
        lblLayers.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 3).Value
        lblTotalParts.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 3).Value
        lblPackagingInstructs.Text = shXL.Cells(12, 3).Value

        'Pulls pictures from designated part folder
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicSpindle" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picSpindle.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicSpindle" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picSpindle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picSpindle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorTop" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picRotorTop.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorTop" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picRotorTop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picRotorTop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorBottom" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picRotorBottom.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorBottom" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picRotorBottom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picRotorBottom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageFinal" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picDunnageFinal.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageFinal" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picDunnageFinal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picDunnageFinal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageLayer" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picDunnageLayer.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageLayer" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picDunnageLayer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picDunnageLayer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        ' Close objects
        shXL = Nothing
        wbXl.Close()
        appXL.Quit()
        appXL = Nothing
    Else
        lblCODE.Text = ("Error")
        lblCODE.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblREV.Text = ("Error")
        lblREV.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblDate.Text = ("Error")
        lblDate.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblCustomer.Text = ("Error")
        lblCustomer.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPart.Text = ("Error")
        lblPart.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblSpindleType.Text = ("Error")
        lblSpindleType.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPaintType.Text = ("Error")
        lblPaintType.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblDunnageType.Text = ("Error")
        lblDunnageType.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Lable49.Text = ("Error")
        Lable49.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblLayers.Text = ("Error")
        lblLayers.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblTotalParts.Text = ("Error")
        lblTotalParts.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPackagingInstructs.Text = ("Error")
        lblPackagingInstructs.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblError.Visible = True
    End If
    timeUpDate = 599
    tmrUpdate.Start()
    Application.DoEvents()

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Wait()
                   End Sub)
    ReferenceCardDataPull()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUpdate.Tick
    Dim hms = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeUpDate)
    Dim m = hms.Minutes.ToString
    Dim s = hms.Seconds.ToString

    If timeUpDate > 0 Then
        timeUpDate -= 1
        lblTimer.Text = (m & ":" & s)

    Else

        tmrUpdate.Stop()
        lblTimer.Text = "Updating"

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

**Updated Code using** `Marshal.objectrelease`

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
'Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook**** Archive
'Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet**** Archive
Dim wbXls As Excel.Workbooks
Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FldPath As String
Dim PartID As String
Dim RefCard As String
Dim timeUpDate As Double
Dim OpenFolder As Object = CreateObject("shell.application")


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Dispaly Brembo Logo
    picLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    ReferenceCardDataPull()
End Sub

Private Sub Wait()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
End Sub
Private Async Sub ReferenceCardDataPull()
    'Prepare For Load
    lblTimer.Text = "Updating"
    lblError.Visible = False

    'Read File Source with part number ******************
    PartID = ("19.N111.10")


    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = False

    'Open Reference Card*************************************************************************************
    FldPath = ("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Kaizens\Kaizen 44 - Missing Parts\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number" & "\" & PartID)
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(FldPath) Then

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & PartID & ".xlsm") Then
            'wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Open(FldPath & "\" & PartID & ".xlsm")**** Archive

            wbXls = appXL.Workbooks
            wbXl = wbXls.Open(FldPath & "\" & PartID & ".xlsm")
            shXL = wbXl.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            ' Copys Reference Card Data by Cell To App labels
            lblCODE.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 5).Value
            lblREV.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 5).Value
            lblDate.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 5).Value
            lblCustomer.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 1).Value
            lblPart.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 1).Value
            lblSpindleType.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 1).Value
            lblPaintType.Text = shXL.Cells(12, 1).Value
            lblDunnageType.Text = shXL.Cells(15, 1).Value
            lblPartsLayer.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 3).Value
            lblLayers.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 3).Value
            lblTotalParts.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 3).Value
            lblPackagingInstructs.Text = shXL.Cells(12, 3).Value
        Else
            lblCODE.Text = ("Error")
            lblREV.Text = ("Error")
            lblDate.Text = ("Error")
            lblCustomer.Text = ("Error")
            lblPart.Text = ("Error")
            lblSpindleType.Text = ("Error")
            lblPaintType.Text = ("Error")
            lblDunnageType.Text = ("Error")
            Lable49.Text = ("Error")
            lblLayers.Text = ("Error")
            lblTotalParts.Text = ("Error")
            lblPackagingInstructs.Text = ("Error")
            lblError.Visible = True

            ' Close objects**** Archive
            ' shXL = Nothing**** Archive
            ' wbXl.Close()**** Archive
            'appXL.Quit()**** Archive
            'appXL = Nothing**** Archive



        End If

    Else
        'File not found Error
        lblCODE.Text = ("Error")
        lblREV.Text = ("Error")
        lblDate.Text = ("Error")
        lblCustomer.Text = ("Error")
        lblPart.Text = ("Error")
        lblSpindleType.Text = ("Error")
        lblPaintType.Text = ("Error")
        lblDunnageType.Text = ("Error")
        Lable49.Text = ("Error")
        lblLayers.Text = ("Error")
        lblTotalParts.Text = ("Error")
        lblPackagingInstructs.Text = ("Error")
        lblError.Visible = True
    End If

    'Pulls pictures from designated part folder
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicSpindle" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
        picSpindle.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicSpindle" & PartID & ".JPG")
        picSpindle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        picSpindle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorTop" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
        picRotorTop.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorTop" & PartID & ".JPG")
        picRotorTop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        picRotorTop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorBottom" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
        picRotorBottom.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorBottom" & PartID & ".JPG")
        picRotorBottom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        picRotorBottom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageFinal" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
        picDunnageFinal.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageFinal" & PartID & ".JPG")
        picDunnageFinal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        picDunnageFinal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageLayer" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
        picDunnageLayer.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageLayer" & PartID & ".JPG")
        picDunnageLayer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        picDunnageLayer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If

    ' Close objects
    wbXl.Close()
    wbXls.Close()
    appXL.Quit()
    'Release Objects
    releaseObject(shXL)
    releaseObject(wbXl)
    releaseObject(wbXl)
    releaseObject(wbXls)
    releaseObject(appXL)

    timeUpDate = 9
    tmrUpdate.Start()
    Application.DoEvents()
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Wait()

                   End Sub)
    ReferenceCardDataPull()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUpdate.Tick
    Dim hms = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeUpDate)
    Dim m = hms.Minutes.ToString
    Dim s = hms.Seconds.ToString

    If timeUpDate > 0 Then
        timeUpDate -= 1
        lblTimer.Text = (m & ":" & s)

    Else

        tmrUpdate.Stop()
        lblTimer.Text = "Preparing Update"

    End If

End Sub
Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        Dim intRel As Integer = 0
        Do
            intRel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        Loop While intRel > 0
        'MsgBox("Final Released obj # " & intRel)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error releasing object" & ex.ToString)
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please take a look **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit** there. Look at the excepted answer about releasing objects, this may be of help...

Comment: @Duraholiday, I don't know why I got down vote but I can tell you for sure this is the answer to your question. Have a look at it, it will help you

Comment: @ehh that is why I posted the link, it was the same problem I was having...

Comment: @Codexer I have the same issue 2 days ago at work and I posted the PrintExcel method I wrote.

Comment: @Codexer, just understand why you downvote. Anyway, I look at the solution you got and as you mentioned there, it cannot work. It work for Word but not for excel. The reason is the dots as I wrote in my solution below. Workbooks object is not close and not release. Review you link and the solution you got.

Comment: @ehh, ok so no it didn't work. I fixed the excel issue, now I need to end connect with the pictures and folder.

Comment: The excel is fixed? What didn't work?

Comment: Moved `ReferenceCardDataPull()` from the wait sub and put it after ``Await Task.Run(Sub()`` So now the folder and picture files are still open in the background

Comment: You question: "why isn't the wbXl.Close() and  appXL.Quit() not working?" was an excel issue and this is what I answered and fixed.

Comment: I guess I didn't fix it. Still is doing it even with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workink with COM in .Net requires to release com objects. More than that, you cannot use dots when working with excel interop (or any other COM object) in .Net since between the dots, temporarly objects are created behind the scene and need to be released.
For example, you wrote:

```
appXL.Workbooks.Open
```

You need to split it to

```
Dim workbooks as Excel.Workbooks
workbooks = appXL.WorkBooks
workbooks.Open
...
When time to release, you need to call Marhsal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks).
```

You must do it for all the excel objects you have in the code.
An example of the usage of excel in VB.Net:

```
Public Function PrintExcel(sPath As String, iFrom As Integer) As String Implements IPrint.PrintExcel
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

    Try
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(sPath)
        xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkSheets(1)

       ' DO SOMETHING

        xlWorkBook.Close()

        xlWorkBooks.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheets)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBooks)
        releaseObject(xlApp)


    End Try
    Return s
End Function

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        obj = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

' ----------------------

Following your code with the fix, not checked:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
  Dim appXL As Excel.Application
  Dim wbXls As Excel.Workbooks
  Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
  Dim shXLs As Excel.Sheets    ' FIX 1: Sheets instead of WorkSheets
  Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim FldPath As String
  Dim PartID As String
  Dim RefCard As String
  Dim timeUpDate As Double

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Dispaly Brembo Logo
    picLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    ReferenceCardDataPull()
End Sub

Private Sub Wait()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(600000)
End Sub
Private Async Sub ReferenceCardDataPull()

    'Read File Source with part number ******************
    PartID = ("19.N111.10")

    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = False

    'Open Reference Card*************************************************************************************
    FldPath = ("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Kaizens\Kaizen 44 - Missing Parts\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number" & "\" & PartID)
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(FldPath) Then
        wbXls = appXL.Workbooks
        wbXl = wbXls.Open(FldPath & "\" & PartID & ".xlsm")
        shXLs = wbXl.Worksheets
        shXL = shXLs("Sheet1")

        ' Copys Reference Card Data by Cell To App labels
        lblCODE.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 5).Value
        lblREV.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 5).Value
        lblDate.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 5).Value
        lblCustomer.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 1).Value
        lblPart.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 1).Value
        lblSpindleType.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 1).Value
        lblPaintType.Text = shXL.Cells(12, 1).Value
        lblDunnageType.Text = shXL.Cells(15, 1).Value
        lblPartsLayer.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 3).Value
        lblLayers.Text = shXL.Cells(6, 3).Value
        lblTotalParts.Text = shXL.Cells(9, 3).Value
        lblPackagingInstructs.Text = shXL.Cells(12, 3).Value

        'Pulls pictures from designated part folder
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicSpindle" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picSpindle.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicSpindle" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picSpindle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picSpindle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorTop" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picRotorTop.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorTop" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picRotorTop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picRotorTop.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorBottom" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picRotorBottom.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicRotorBottom" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picRotorBottom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picRotorBottom.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageFinal" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picDunnageFinal.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageFinal" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picDunnageFinal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picDunnageFinal.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageLayer" & PartID & ".JPG") Then
            picDunnageLayer.Image = Image.FromFile(FldPath & "\" & "PicDunnageLayer" & PartID & ".JPG")
            picDunnageLayer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Else
            picDunnageLayer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        End If

        ' Close objects
                          ' FIX 2: remove shXL = Nothing
        wbXl.Close()
        wbXls.Close()
        appXL.Quit()
                          ' FIX 3: remove appXL = Nothing           
        releaseObject(shXL)
        releaseObject(shXLs)
        releaseObject(wbXl)
        releaseObject(wbXls)
        releaseObject(appXL)


    Else
        lblCODE.Text = ("Error")
        lblCODE.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblREV.Text = ("Error")
        lblREV.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblDate.Text = ("Error")
        lblDate.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblCustomer.Text = ("Error")
        lblCustomer.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPart.Text = ("Error")
        lblPart.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblSpindleType.Text = ("Error")
        lblSpindleType.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPaintType.Text = ("Error")
        lblPaintType.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblDunnageType.Text = ("Error")
        lblDunnageType.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Lable49.Text = ("Error")
        Lable49.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblLayers.Text = ("Error")
        lblLayers.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblTotalParts.Text = ("Error")
        lblTotalParts.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPackagingInstructs.Text = ("Error")
        lblPackagingInstructs.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblError.Visible = True
    End If
    timeUpDate = 599
    tmrUpdate.Start()
    Application.DoEvents()

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Wait()
                   End Sub)
    ReferenceCardDataPull()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUpdate.Tick
    Dim hms = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeUpDate)
    Dim m = hms.Minutes.ToString
    Dim s = hms.Seconds.ToString

    If timeUpDate > 0 Then
        timeUpDate -= 1
        lblTimer.Text = (m & ":" & s)

    Else

        tmrUpdate.Stop()
        lblTimer.Text = "Updating"

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            If obj IsNot Nothing Then
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            obj = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: so instead of the If file exist method use try?

Comment: No this is not the problem you have, you need to release COM objects in order to prevent excel to be stuck in your task manager or as you said in use.

Comment: You forgot to add `GC.Collect()` in the releaseObject method... It's important as well. The link I provided above explains this...

Comment: No need to call GC.Collect(). There are lot of posts on this. One of them: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26993

Comment: Went back over your code and what is `Marshal` Cause that is what is erroring out. says not declared

Comment: Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: Yeah I googled Marshal Class Syntax. Still gives me the read only, file in use

Comment: Ok so I step though the program using your code while watching the task manager processes. While stepping through the code I see the code create the first Excel process but doesn't release it. When it loops around the 2nd,3rd,4th time etc It creates another new excel process and then releases the 2nd one. Never the first instance though.

Comment: It is maybe because async. Can you try to run it non async.

Comment: @Duraholiday, I fixed the code to remove excel.exe from task manager. Look at Fix 1, Fix 2 and Fix 3 that were be done. I also try it on my machine and it works fine, excel is not stuck anymore.

Comment: @Duraholiday, does the fix helped?