# C# set Excel chart source

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to do something, but have a hard time. Idea is that i just loop trough excel sheet and find all charts, set it source and then move that sheet to the end of workbook.

I am using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

**EDIT**

Reason why I need foreach loop, is that because I don't know how much charts I gonna have on that sheet, as I want to allow user to just put charts in sheet, after I dynamically get data from SQL and put it in another sheet, I need to update these charts

This is what I tried so far

```
// Get source for charts
Excel.Range ChartSourceRange = xlWorkSheet3.Range["A4", "G5"];

// Here becomes the problem ...I don't know how to go foreach in excel sheet
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject item in xlWorkBook.Sheets[2])
{
    item.Chart.SetSourceData(ChartSourceRange);
}

int totalSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count;
xlWorkBook.Sheets[2].Move(xlWorkBook.Sheets[totalSheets]);
```

This code gives me exception ...

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to 
interface type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the 
interface with IID '{496B0ABE-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}' failed 
due to the following error: 'No such interface 
supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))' 
and the COM component does not support IDispatch::Invoke calls for DISPID_NEWENUM.
```

Can you toss me advice, how to change this code, so that my foreach can go through excel sheet?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach (xl.ChartObject item in xlWorkBook.Sheets[2].ChartObjects())
{
     item.Chart.SetSourceData(ChartSourceRange);
}
```

In addition, I suggest you to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318070/excel-workbook-folder-and-picture-files-not-closing-ending-completely/35318311#35318311) in order to know how to use excel in C# (or VB.Net). Since it is a COM object, you need to release it properly: