# .Net Interop Excel ExportAsFixedFormat() Exception HResult: 0x800A03EC

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop, comexception

I'm currently implementing a method that generated multiple sheets and export them as PDF. For this I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop Library (v14.0.0.0) with .NET 4.5.2 . Running Office is 2016

My code:

```
Dim excel As New Application()
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim workbooks As Workbooks
workbooks = excel.Workbooks
Dim workbook As Workbook = workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)

[...]

workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, String.Format(<a Path>)
ReleaseComObject(workSheet)
workbook.Close()
ReleaseComObject(workbook)
excel.Quit()
ReleaseComObject(excel)
```

The ReleaseComObject() looks like this (according to [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317109/office-application-does-not-quit-after-automation-from-visual-studio-.net-client)):

```
Private Sub ReleaseComObject(objectToRelease As Object)
        While System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objectToRelease) > 0
        End While
        objectToRelease = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works fine if I run this code for one iteration **BUT** I noticed that the EXCEL-Process is still running.

If I try to do this in batch-mode (in the meaning of a for-loop) I get an excetion when entering the 2nd interation:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>      bei Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType Type, Object Filename, Object Quality, Object IncludeDocProperties, Object IgnorePrintAreas, Object From, Object To, Object OpenAfterPublish, Object FixedFormatExtClassPtr)
>      bei Controller.CreateListing(DataTable data, Int32 year, String mandantShortName) in ...

Line that throws exception:

```
workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, String.Format(<a Path>)
```

For reseach/testing I debugged before reentering the loop and killed the excel-process but w/o any changes.

Anyone faced this problem as well? Solutions/Suggestions?

Comment: Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to address the issue with `Excel` not closing properly replace:

```
Private Sub ReleaseComObject(objectToRelease As Object)
    While System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objectToRelease) > 0
    End While
    objectToRelease = Nothing
End Sub
```

With this bit of [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15698337/6375113) as illustrated by [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout):

```
Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        Dim intRel As Integer = 0
        Do
            intRel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        Loop While intRel > 0
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

You could use your `While` statement instead of the `Do` statement but I feel it reads better this way. The important bit here is `GC.Collect()`.

You also have to make sure you release in the right order and release *everything*. This is usually in *backwards* order. So in your case, start off with the `workSheet` then the `workbook` then `workbooks` and then lastly `excel`:

```
ReleaseObject(workSheet)
workbook.Close()
ReleaseObject(workbook)
ReleaseObject(workbooks)
excel.Quit()
ReleaseObject(excel)
```

This is the code I put together to test:

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application()
app.Visible = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wbs As Excel.Workbooks = app.Workbooks
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = wbs.Add()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

ReleaseObject(ws)
wb.Close()
ReleaseObject(wb)
ReleaseObject(wbs)
app.Quit()
ReleaseObject(app)
```

The process starts and once `ReleaseObject(app)` has been called the process then closes.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out what the problem caused (own Bug).

But it still leaves the question open, why the Excel-Proccess ain't closing.

Comment: Well I just had an inner implementation bug which doesn't matter in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run application or service as administration account. This solved my problem.