# How to properly quit Excel

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print a receipt from `Excel` but unable to do so. I have tried release in reverse but I seems can't find what is missing. Kindly help! Thank you!

**This is what i have done so far :**

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

#Region "dim"
    Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
    Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "SampleReceipt.xls")
    Dim app As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim books As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim sheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim cell As Excel.Range = Nothing
#End Region

    Private Sub NAR(ByVal o As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)
        Catch ex As Exception
            o = Nothing
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            app = New Excel.Application()
            books = app.Workbooks
            book = books.Open(xlPath)
            sheets = book.Sheets
            sheet = book.Sheets(1)
            cell = sheet.Range("A1")
            cell.Value = "Lorem Ipsum"
            book.SaveAs("C:\Temp\ExcelBook.xls")
            book.Close()
            app.Quit()
        Finally
            NAR(cell)
            NAR(sheet)
            NAR(sheets)
            NAR(book)
            NAR(books)
            NAR(app)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Check this answer:
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel application not quitting after calling quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/excel-application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit)

Comment: @Enigmativity, kindly explain further where I missed it?

Comment: @SubazSarma, hi sir! ive also checked the 2 dot rule. Cant seem to find where I missed something here. (ty for the correction as well)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but I don't think your `NAR` method is doing the job perfectly well.

You have this:

```
Private Sub NAR(ByVal o As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)
    Catch ex As Exception
        o = Nothing
    Finally

    End Try
End Sub
```

Now, if you have an `Exception` raised by `ReleaseComObject` then you're just swallowing it - I would think that you want to see what the exception is. You really should only handle exceptions that you can recover from. Handling the top-level `Exception` really is an anti-pattern. So if `ReleaseComObject` is raising an exception then find out what it is and deal with that specifically.

Next, if you do have an exception you are then trying to set the reference to `Nothing`, but you're only setting a **copy of the reference** to `Nothing`. You're passing in `o` using `ByVal`. The original reference is untouched. You want to pass it in `ByRef`. Try that.

Also, It might be required that you set the reference to `Nothing` after releasing the component - so move it out of the `Catch`.

And finally, the [help docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx) on `ReleaseComObject` says this:

> If you want to call this method to ensure that a COM component is released at a determined time, consider using the `FinalReleaseComObject` method instead. `FinalReleaseComObject` will release the underlying COM component regardless of how many times it has re-entered the CLR. The internal reference count of the RCW is incremented by one every time the COM component re-enters the CLR. Therefore, you could call the `ReleaseComObject` method in a loop until the value returned is zero. This achieves the same result as the `FinalReleaseComObject` method.

I'd try those three things.

Try this code:

```
Private Sub NAR(ByRef o As Object)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o)
    o = Nothing
End Sub
```

And, only put in exception handling if you have a specific exception to handle, but keep the `o = Nothing` out of the handling code.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity! Thank you for your input, let me try this!