# Excel process running after closing VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, taskbar

I've created a function in my Vb.Net application where I allow the user to export DataGridView data to Excel. What happens is I save the file, then ask the user if they want to view it. If they chose yes then I open excel and display the data to them like this...

```
        If x = vbYes Then
            Process.Start("Excel.exe", filename)
        End If

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseobject(xlApp)
        releaseobject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseobject(xlWorkSheet)
```

and

```
    Private Sub releaseobject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        gc.collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

This looks like it should take care of instance of Excel running in the background. I've tested it multiple times. The data opens fine, everything is okay, then I close it. Each time after I run this function I still see Excel runnign in the processes. Any Ideas?

If need be, i can display my other code...lmk

Comment: See this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222501/excel-process-not-closing-in-vb-net?rq=1

Comment: I've always released the objects in the opposite order you are, i.e. `releaseobject` sheet, then book, then app. But linked question looks like an exact duplicate, even with some identical code.

Comment: Yeah looks like we got our code from the same source :)

Comment: Interestingly I had a Try Catch Finally End Try and that seemed to be the reason for the instance of it running in the background

Comment: In your case @Bobski I think the order you were releasing things may have been a factor.  Worksheet, then Workbook, then the Excel App

Comment: @JimmySmith the thing is jimmy - I had a try catch Finally (here i included releasing) and end try. once I removed it, everything works fine!

Comment: Ill try it in the correct order

Comment: Yeah, actually... your .Quit should do the job, but with the code hitting the next line before that finishes then the garbage collector `gc.Collect()` may have been taking Excel for a spin before closing.

Comment: If you're debugging, try stop the program instead of closing Excel.